# Android send simple HTTP command

Tags: android, http, browser

How to send a simple http command without opening the browser??

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent browserIntent = 
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.95:8080/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=2&switchcmd=Off&level=0"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I know what you want to do. A simple example [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient), could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[`HTTPClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) is what you are looking for. Make sure to use it in a background thread, e.g. in an `AsyncTask`.

A tutorial like this will get you started: http://hmkcode.com/android-internet-connection-using-http-get-httpclient/

Answer (score 0):

The same question [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Simply, here is the code ( http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/ )

```
 // Creating HTTP client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.example.com/login");

        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                "Hi, trying Android HTTP post!"));

        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```